# What is the Visual Studio Code editor built on

Tags: node-webkit, atom-editor, visual-studio-code, electron

What underlying technologies/libraries is Microsoft's new *(free)* cross platform editor **[Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)** *(Launched 5/29/2015)*  built on? There are rumors that it's just Github's Atom Editor rebranded.

Comment: Also: [What is the framework behind VSCode UI?](https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/hpafjq/what_is_the_framework_behind_vscode_ui/)

Answer (score 304, accepted):

Visual Studio Code is built using web technologies on top of Github's [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/).

Electron is an app runtime for writing *native* apps that uses [Chromium](https://www.chromium.org/) *(which Google Chrome is built on)* for rendering the interface and [node.js](https://nodejs.org/) for local APIs *(example: file system access)*, it was built primarily as the shell for Github's [Atom](https://atom.io/) code editor. *(Note: Electron is very similar to [NW.js](http://nwjs.io/))*.

Node.js is a *(JavaScript)* app runtime built on Google's V8 JavaScript engine with C and C++ code to give it access to native APIs for each operating system *(example: file system access)*.

Essentially, Microsoft's new product is built completely upon open source software whose major components were created by Google.

There are rumors that Visual Studio code is either a fork or rebranding of Github's Atom Editor. This is not even remotely true. Inspecting the source of Visual Studio Code reveals that it uses Electron and [Atom Shell Archive](https://github.com/atom/asar), but nothing else is from the Atom editor.

The 'editor' *(the thing that renders the code with syntax highlighting, line numbers, etc..)* part of Visual Studio Code is Microsoft's Monaco editor. It is the same editor used for OneDrive, Windows Azure, TypeScript Playground, and Visual Studio Online. I have yet to find any real documentation on this editor from Microsoft but there are [some articles](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ARichNewJavaScriptCodeEditorSpreadingToSeveralMicrosoftWebSites.aspx) about it around the web.

[Omnisharp](http://www.omnisharp.net/) is used to provide IntelliSense and other code editing tools for C# *(example: refactoring)*.

The JavaScript Intellisense appears to be all custom code. It provides impressive JavaScript completions but it many cases it appears to be inferior to [Tern](http://ternjs.net/) *(see [Tern Demo](http://sevin7676.github.io/Ace.Tern/demo.html))*.

Comment: I have been looking into Code for a day and it changed my view regarding JS in a desktop App. I looked at Atom and was very dissapointed, as it could not do basic things I expect it to do from a text editor. Code proved me wrong, what text editor control can I use in my node-desktop/web-app ?

Comment: @elcuco - The Ace Editor (http://ace.c9.io/build/kitchen-sink.html) and Code Mirror (https://codemirror.net/) are HTML code editors (I personally prefer Ace).

Comment: What is nice to see is the software greats making a come back, I believe Erik Gamma (GoF) has been involved in the tooling for Visual Studio code and as yet unreleased online "monaco" and Anders Hejslberg (creator of Pascal/ Delphi) is largely responsible for Typescript (Superset of Javascript making it type safe)

Comment: Visual Studio Code is now open source, under MIT license: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode

Comment: The Monaco editor is now [open source](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor) as well, and has a good deal of [documentation on their hub](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor), including [extensive API documentation](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/index.html)

Comment: Did they use only HTML and CSS for the UI or an UI framework?